# Using lambda function to find a minimum value in a std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, unordered-map, std

I am trying to find the element with the minimum value in the map. For example, if my map has

```
 { (1, 12.3),(2, 6.51), (3, 1.24)}
```

I would like to find the element `(3, 1.24)`.

---

I wrote the following code, which tries to write a comparator in the lambda format

```
std::pair<int, double> min = *std::min_element(
    my_map.begin(), my_map.end(),
    [](std::unordered_map<int, double> a, std::unordered_map<int, double> b) { return a.second < b.second; });
```

But I got the following errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at my_code.cpp:118:9)'
            if (__comp(*__i, *__first))
                ^~~~~~
my_code.cpp:116:40: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::min_element<std::__1::__hash_map_iterator<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<int, double>, void *> *> >, (lambda at my_code.cpp:118:9)>' requested here
    std::pair<int, double> min = *std::min_element(
                                       ^
my_code.cpp:118:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::__hash_map_iterator<std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<int, double>, void *> *> >::value_type' (aka 'pair<const int, double>') to 'std::unordered_map<int, double>' for 1st argument
        [](std::unordered_map<int, double> a, std::unordered_map<int, double> b) { return a.second < b.second; });
        ^
my_code.cpp:118:9: note: conversion candidate of type 'void (*)(std::unordered_map<int, double>, std::unordered_map<int, double>)'
3 errors generated.
```

Any idea what I did wrong and what's the proper way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: lambda takes iterators from the hash map, not maps. You want to compare two pairs of values, not maps.

Comment: works now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to use lambda that accepts maps themselves, not elements of it:

```
[](std::unordered_map<int, double> a, std::unordered_map<int, double> b)
```

so it's either (verbose):

```
[](std::unordered_map<int, double>::value_type a, std::unordered_map<int, double>::value_type b)
```

or simpler:

```
[](std::pair<int, double> a, std::pair<int, double> b)
```

or if you have c++14 or later:

```
[](auto a, auto b)
```

you may also consider to pass elements by const reference not to copy them for every iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Your lambda should be binary predicate which takes two pairs of `std::pair<const int, double>`.

Change the lambda to as follows:

```
std::pair<int, double> min = *std::min_element(
    my_map.begin(), my_map.end(),
    [](const auto &a, const auto &b) { return a.second < b.second; });
```

or more explicitly:

```
std::pair<int, double> min = *std::min_element(
    my_map.begin(), my_map.end(),
    [](const std::pair<const int, double> &a, const std::pair<const int, double> &b) { return a.second < b.second; });
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```